# Element of $H^{0,1}_{\overline{\partial}}(T^2)$ representing $\mathbb{C}$-bundle

Tags: homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

Consider a standard complex torus $\mathbf{T}=\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}\oplus i\mathbb{Z}).$ It could be obtained in another way.

$\mathbf{T}$ is a quotient $(\mathbb{C}^\times)^2/\mathbb{C}.$ Here $\mathbb{C}$ is acts on $\mathbb{C}^2$ by multiplication:

$$
z\circ (x,y)=(e^{z}\cdot x, e^{iz}y)\in \mathbb{C}^2.
$$

The bundle $(\mathbb{C}^\times)^2\to \mathbf{T}$ is represented by a certain class in Cech cohomology group ${\check{H}}^1(\mathbf{T};H).$ Here $H$ is a complex Lie group isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}.$ By Dolbeault theorem this group is isomorphic to $H^{0,1}_{\overline{\partial}}(\mathbf{T})\cong \overline{T}^\vee.$ Here $\overline{T}^\vee$ is a space of antiholomorphic covectors on the tangent space of $\mathbf{T}$ at zero.

My question is: which class represents the bundle $(\mathbb{C}^\times)^2\to \mathbf{T}?$

Comment: So have you worked out which element of $\check{H}^1(\mathbf{T};\mathcal{O})$ it is?  Now take a look at [this answer](/a/3610383).

Comment: @user10354138 No, I did not, that is the essence of the question

Comment: Is $(\mathbb C^\times)^2$ supposed to be a line bundle? If yes, how is the addition and scalar multiplication defined?

Comment: No, it is not a line bundle, but a $\mathbb{C}^1$-bundle. Maybe there is a line bundle structure but I know nothing of it.